# Read/Write values in the complex object into the session in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to migrate an application from .NET Framework to .NET Core.

In .NET Framework, we could add objects into sessions as follows.

```
public static Person person
{
    get
    {
        if (session == null) 
            return null;

        if (session["Person"] == null) 
        {
            session["Person"] = new Person();
        }

        return session["Person"] as Person;
    }
    set
    {
        if (session == null) 
            return;

        session["Person"] = value;
    }
}
```

We could just update the properties of a `Person` to update it into the session.

```
person.Name = 'John Doe'; // This will update the value in the session
```

In .NET Core, the same thing can be written as:

```
public static Person person
{
    get
    {
        if (session == null) 
            return null;

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(session.GetString("Person"));
    }
    set
    {
        if (session == null) 
            return;

        session.SetString("Person", JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Person()));
    }
}
```

But here to update the person, we have the set the object again explicitly into the session.

```
var personObj = person;
personObj.name = "John Doe";

// Set object again.
Session.SetString("Person", JsonSerializer.Serializer(personObj));
```

Is there any better way to do this in .NET Core?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Just write a few extension methods around it yourself if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We could just update the properties of a Person to update it into the
> session, here to update the person, we have the set the object again
> explicitly into the sessionIs there any better way to do this in .NET
> Core?

It can be improved by using `SerializeObject` and `DeserializeObject<T>`  as fowlloing:

You could create an extension method on session：

```
public static class SessionExtension
    {
        //setting session
        public static void SetComplexObjectSession(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        //getting session
        public static T GetComplexObjectSession<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

Finally, you can implement  it within your code:

```
var personObj = new Person()
            {
                Name = "New Person In Session"
            };

 HttpContext.Session.SetComplexObjectSession("John Doe", personObj);

 var objFromSession = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexObjectSession<Person>("John Doe");
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

This how you could improve the current implementation. Therefore, to point your question, yes this is the contemporary way to achieve it. However, [you could check our official document for few more ways as well.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) Furthermore, I found this implementation more convenient and efficint way as of now.